# Having trouble with Ubuntu LAMP stack

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Apache2, Mysql 14, Php7. I have installed Drupal with a few difficulties. Specifically, I had to install php extensions and tweak the configs to enable those extensions, and finally the installation was successful. However, whenever I try to click on any link, the 404 Not found error page pops up. So technically I can't go anywhere beyond the CMS homepage. I installed another CMS, the same problem, can see the homepage, nothing beyond. Did anyone ever had this kind of issue? 
I tried the following three:
changed the CMS folder ownership to www-data:www-data (my CMS folder is drupaltest)

```
sudo chown -R /var/www/html/drupaltest
```

in /etc/apache2/apache.conf file, added

```
<Directory /var/www/html/drupaltest/> 
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And also:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: Sounds like request rewriting does not work as expected. Most of these simply CMS solution rely on being able to write and modify a dynamic configuration file in their own folder. That is a huge security issue, but apparently standard with these systems. Check if the http server process itself has write permissions in the CMS file system folder. It should be able to create and modify a `.htaccess` file in there. Also your http servers host settings have to enable rewriting in such files, take a look at the `AllowOverride` directive in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're missing .htaccess file. Usually its a hidden file, so make sure to show all files (including hidden files) and copy it and paste it into your local drupal folder.

Also,make sure you local server has mod_rewrite enabled to support clean URLs, if its not enabled then check this answer: How to enable mod_rewrite in Apache?.

Another suggestion is to turn off Clean URL from settings.php by adding the following code:

$conf['clean_url'] = 0;

if all these above step not working then please explain little more about your problem .